# Ordering posts by date created and then highest voted using Thumbs Up

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to group posts (called Topic) by date first, so that the newest comes on top. After that, I want to display the highest voted for that date on the top.

Here's my controller: topics_controller.rb

```
@topics = Topic.tally.group(created_at: :desc).order('vote_count')
```

But my output comes out like this,

[image: index.html.erb]

I want 28th post, 27th post and then 26th post to be displayed.
What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: 
Here's a sample of how I want my posts page to look.

**Sept 28** 
Post 5, 10 upvotes 
Post 4, 7 upvotes

**Sept 27** 
Post 3, 17 upvotes 
Post 2, 15 upvotes

**Sept 26** 
Post 1, 26 upvote

Comment: You want to ordering by date, why you're using `group`?

Comment: Not an answer but looking at your UI, you have Title and Body so why are you using group on them? I mean it'll always show the first post in body and title so can you explain your use case a bit? Also in order clause you are using vote_count but it should be `'created_at desc'`

Comment: What I want to do is group by date so I get sections. And in that section arrange the posts by vote.

Comment: @SwaathiK Ahh okay! what is tally and what is the relation between topics and tally?

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
@topics = Topic.tally.group(created_at: :desc).order('created_at,vote_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL's GROUP BY (AKA `group` with ActiveRecord) doesn't do what you think it does. You say that:

> I'm trying to group posts (called Topic) by date first, so that the newest comes on top.

but you don't use GROUP BY to order things, you use use GROUP BY to group rows so that an aggregation operation (such as `count`, `sum`, `avg`, ...) can collapse the grouped rows to produce a summary of some sort.

If you want to order things then order them:

```
@topics = Topic.tally.order('created_at desc, vote_count asc')
```

Of course, since your `created_at` timestamps are probably unique (or nearly so), the `vote_count` will be effectively ignored as there won't be any `created_at` ties that need breaking. You say that you want to sort by *date* but `created_at` is a *timestamp* (i.e. date and time-of-day). If you really want to sort by date then cast `created_at` to a date:

```
@topics = Topic.tally.order('cast(created_at as date) desc, vote_count asc')
```

Comment: I don't want to order the posts by date, what I meant when I said that "the newest comes on top" is, to group posts together based on date so that posts made today will come on top. And then those posts in "today" group are ordered by votes.
So, the posts will look like this
Sept 28
Post 5, 10 upvotes
Post 4, 7 upvotes
Sept 27
Post 3, 17 upvotes
Post 2, 15 upvotes
Sept 26
Post 1, 26 upvotes

Comment: Maybe you need to supply some sample output to clarify things.

Comment: I added the sample output to the question! Hope it helps :)

Comment: So pull them out of the database as above and then detect a date change while iterating in your view and change the first column when the date changes. Or throw in an `Enumerable#group_by` call to group them all at once.